# Solution for window is not define in React server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, input-mask

I am trying to integrate React server-side rendering to existing React application. I am using webpack with babel to transpile JS code.

*webpack.config.js*

```
const { join, resolve } = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const projectConfig = require('../../config');

const APP_JS = 'server/index.js';

const prodConfig = {
    entry: [
        join(process.cwd(), APP_JS),
    ],

    output: {
        path: resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },

    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        whitelist: [/^lodash-es/],
    })],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'Framework/Services$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'services')),
            'Framework/UI$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'uiComponents.js')),
            'Framework/Utils$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'utils')),
            'Framework/Middleware$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'middleware')),
            'Framework/Constants$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'constants')),
            'Framework/Auth$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'modules', 'auth')),
            'Framework/System$': resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'modules', 'system')),
            Framework$: resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'internal', 'actions.js')),
            Modules$: resolve(process.cwd(), join('app', 'modules')),
            lodash: 'lodash-es',
        },
        modules: [
            'app', 'node_modules',
        ],
        extensions: [
            '.js', '.json', '.css',
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en|fr/),

        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/react-intl[/\\]locale-data$/, /en|fr/),


        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            // make fetch available
            fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        }),

        // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside your code for any environment checks.
        // UglifyJS will automatically drop any unreachable code.
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(projectConfig({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            },
            __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        })),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!lodash-es\/)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                // pre-process our own .css files
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                // pre-process 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },

};

module.exports = () => prodConfig;
```

part of the *server/index.js*

```js
// Renders app component into an HTML string
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App));

// app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(resolve(outputPath, 'index.html')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  Fs.readFile(resolve(outputPath, 'index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Inserts the rendered React HTML into our main div
    const document = data.replace(/<div id="app"><\/div>/, `<div id="app">${html}</div>`);

    // Sends the response back to the client
    res.send(document);
  });
});
```

But when I start the node server following error is occurring.

```
/node_modules/inputmask/dist/inputmask/global/window.js:11
}) : "object" == typeof exports && (module.exports = window);
                                                     ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

As I understood this error is occurring since inputmask library using *window* object which is not available in the server.
Can anyone suggest any solution or any workaround?

Comment: You could try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom to define a virtual dom before importing inputmask package.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use this package for detect DOM is ready (client/server)

https://github.com/JedWatson/exenv

```
var ExecutionEnvironment = require('exenv');

ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM // window object will be ready
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, But I cannot use this because inputMask is sub dependency. Also seems like `ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM ` check whether there is DOM available or not, It is not creating a DOM in server environment.